# How to write HTML form detail to excel sheet using java script

Tags: javascript, excel, html, forms

Trying to write HTML form detail to excel sheet using below code but that doesn't work.Please someone suggest me if I'm doing something wrong.

```
<HTML>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=JAVASCRIPT>
function saveToExcel(passform){
var fileName = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\Book1.xlsx";
var sheetName = "Sheet1";
var app = Sys.OleObject("Excel.Application");
app.Visible = "True";
var book = app.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
var sheet = book.Sheets(sheetName);    
rowCount = app.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1;
colCount = 1;
sheet.Cells(1,1)= "test";
alert('Data successfully saved');
}
</SCRIPT></style>
<form>
Requested By:
  <input type="text" name="Requested By"><br>
Start Date:
  <input type="date" name="Start Date"><br>
Select time:    
  <input type="time" name="usr_time"><br>
Suite:  
  <input type="text" name="suite"><br>

<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="saveToExcel(this.form)">

</form>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I forgot to add > in question.

Comment: there's no php here, so it's hard to say if the problem is in there or even related.

Comment: why is there a stray `</style>` tag?

Comment: Where are you expecting this code to work?

Comment: now that someone removed the php tag, we don't know if that was relevant or not. This question is unclear in many ways.

Comment: I have 5 text fields on HTML page and submit button on html page.Once I fill the details on HTML page and click on submit button thn form details should be saved in excel sheet.  To achieve above thing ,I am using this code.Please let me know if still question is not clear

Comment: So you're using Javascript to take HTML form data, and save to an Excel file (`.xlsx`/`.xls`?), to clarify.  You're asking how to do this in *Javascript* correct?

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes